# Removal of "Reading this post in our app!" notification

Tags: discussion, android-app, notifications

When any SE network site is accessed from the mobile view, the following notification is shown while viewing questions:

[image]

The picture is from a screenshot in a question in Physics SE, but this problem persists in all network sites. The notification says: "Read this question in our app!"

The problem with this notification is that, while navigating, if somehow I click it, Play Store opens, and shows up the SE app. Many times, on the mobile site, it is possible that the finger may not press the correct field, which often happens with me. Now, every time this notification is clicked, and the Play Store app opens, my phone somehow crashes, though it does not happen if I install an app from Play Store at other times. This has made it irritating.

Everyone here knows about the SE Android app. It is always shown at the bottom of the page in any app, like "Download the SE app." So, I feel this notification should be removed as soon as possible from all network sites.

If, however, this notification is useful to some people, then an alternative would be that, after I dismiss the banner, my choice should be remembered as a cookie or a site setting, so that it won't pop up again until I clear all my site settings from browsing history.

Comment: Well, the banner is also used to open the question on the app directly from the web without having to search it manually on the app. I use it sometimes because I prefer the app than the mobile web (call me crazy, but that's the fact). If else, the alternative proposal is to remember the choice after the banner has been dismissed.

Comment: That's a good idea.